# Invalid constant value when passing custom object as a screen parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, object, parameter-passing

i am trying to pass a custom object called "Lesson" to a screen called "ExamScreen"
here is the call:

```
goStepScreen(int statusId, Lesson lesson, BuildContext context) {
  if (statusId == SessionStates.Revision.getStatus()) {
    navigateTo(context, const ExamScreen(lesson: lesson,));
```

and the exam screen:

```
class ExamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Lesson? lesson;
  const ExamScreen({super.key,  this.lesson});

  @override
  State<ExamScreen> createState() => _ExamScreenState();
}

class _ExamScreenState extends State<ExamScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
```

i get error `Invalid constant value`

how can i solve it

Comment: What does your navigateTo method look like? If it has a const in it, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the const keyword from the `navigateTo`

```
navigateTo(context, const ExamScreen(lesson: lesson,));
```

You receive this error because lesson isn't a constant value, so you cannot create a constant instance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the const keyword from the ExamScreen constructor like this:

```
class ExamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Lesson? lesson;
  ExamScreen({super.key,  this.lesson}); // Here

  @override
  State<ExamScreen> createState() => _ExamScreenState();
}
```